# How to rotate a 2D image with opengl and glsl?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my already existing and functioning vertex shader I have something like this:

```c
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

The aPos is a position vector3 and the uniform variable `projection` is used to obtain screen-space coordinates.

In examples I've seen, the way rotation is implemented is by calculating it in code (which I've already done) and multiplying the result by `vec4(aPos, 1.0);`, however, I have a uniform inside my shader, the others do not `projection` which is already multiplying by vec4(aPos, 1.0).

My question is: **What do I need to do to apply the rotation inside the vertex shader?**

**Do I create another uniform for the rotation result and multiply that one by both the projection and vec4(aPos, 1.0) ?**

**How do I do this?**

Comment: You usually have a transform matrix which you upload as an uniform and multiply by the vertex position.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Something like this: projection * (transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0); ?

Comment: Yes. https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

Comment: @TedKleinBergman That's one of the examples I was talking about, as you can see, only the transform  uniform is used, so, while I do know I need to multiply it by both the projection uniform and vec4(aPos, 1.0) I don't know *in what order*?

Comment: There's a section called _Combining matrices_.  The right-most thing is what gets applied first, and to get correct result you need to first do the transform, then the view transform and lastly the projection, i.e. `gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);`. The next chapter into great detail afterwards about exactly this: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems